# Cannot initialize a mongodb replica set on Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have been trying all day to setup a replica set for MongoDB transactions automated by Docker Compose, but no success so far. Keep encountering the error where `mongo1` (connected from `mongo-setup`) can't connect to `mongo2` and `mongo3` containers, saying `connection refused`.

The error message I got:

```
{

"ok" : 0,

"errmsg" : "replSetInitiate quorum check failed because not all proposed set members responded affirmatively: mongo2:27018 failed with Error connecting to mongo2:27018 (172.30.0.5:27018) :: caused by :: Connection refused, mongo3:27019 failed with Error connecting to mongo3:27019 (172.30.0.4:27019) :: caused by :: Connection refused",

"code" : 74,

"codeName" : "NodeNotFound"

}

uncaught exception: ReferenceError: EOF is not defined :

@(shell):1:1

uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: string literal :

@(shell):1:5
```

My Docker Compose:

```
mongo3:
    hostname: mongo3
    image: mongo:5.0.5-focal
    networks:
      - shopnetwork
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongo3:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27019:27019
    restart: always
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "shop-mongo-set" ]
  mongo2:
    hostname: mongo2
    image: mongo:5.0.5-focal
    networks:
      - shopnetwork
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongo2:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27018:27018
    restart: always
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "shop-mongo-set" ]
  mongo1:
    hostname: mongo1
    image: mongo:5.0.5-focal
    networks:
      - shopnetwork
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongo1:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    depends_on:
      - mongo2
      - mongo3
    restart: always
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "shop-mongo-set" ]
  mongo-setup:
    image: mongo:5.0.5-focal
    networks:
      - shopnetwork
    volumes:
      - ./script:/script
    depends_on:
      - mongo1
      - mongo2
      - mongo3
    entrypoint: ["/script/setup.sh"]
```

My setup.sh to initialize replica set:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting replica set initialize"
until mongo --host mongo1 --eval "print(\"waited for connection\")"
do
    sleep 2
done
echo "Connection finished"
echo "Creating replica set"
mongo --host mongo1 <<EOF
config = {
    "_id" : "shop-mongo-set",
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "mongo1:27017"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "mongo2:27018"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "mongo3:27019"
        }
    ]
  }
  rs.initiate(config)
  EOF
echo "Replica set created"
```

Comment: the ports section in the compose file refers to host ports, also by default since you didn't configure this in any other file the port used for mongo is 27017. try first replacing the ports for all the members to 27017 (you have different hostnames so different ports arent needed internally within the compose network), second, bind the different ports externally to the host but the same port internally in the container (`27017:27017`, `27018:27017`, `27019:27017`)

Comment: @NoamYizraeli Yes! Thank you, that works. I was confused because previously I connected from localhost (my pc) to Redis container and weirdly that was the setting I had to use. Now I have containerized my app and they are in the same network which is why the old config didn't work.

Comment: great! I'll post it as an answer

Comment: Sure. Was a typo, meant to write MongoDB container not Redis haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so as tested with the OP there was a mixup with the network configuration in compose and host network.

when using multiple services in docker-compose each service is a different host in the compose network, so for example if we have multiple services using the same port that won't be an issue because each has a different hostname and IP.

when mapping `ports` from `docker network` to `host network` using `bridge` adapter usually only one `service` can use each port and better to use ports >1024 for security and compatibility reasons.

when wanting to connect to different services in the same `compose file` but no external connection from `WAN` into the `compose network` is needed the `ports` section of the compose file or the `-p` option in the `docker run` command **isn't needed**

after fixing said miss-configuration there shouldn't be any problems around that topic